# Is it possible to create a user in mysql without logging in?

Tags: database, mysql, createuser

I have a root and test user which I don't remember the password for either one in mysql database. is it possible to create a new user from outside? I could not find answers for this in the internet. Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean 'outside'? Outside what? `mysql>` prompt? You will need to use privileged user to grant new privileges as well.

Comment: yeah, outside mysql prompt. if I don't have password for privileged user, is it not possible?

Comment: If you have no other user with `GRANT` privilege - then no, you can't do that. But even if you have such user - you will need to operate with some mysql client (it could be pma, not native mysql shell, but in case of this question that's the same)

Answer (score 1):

Restart mysqld with the [`--init-file`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/server-options.html#option_mysqld_init-file) option specifying the path to a file that contains your desired commands.  For example, to create a new superuser:

```
GRANT ALL ON *.*
  TO 'new_user'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'new_password'
  WITH GRANT OPTION;
```

Of course, you could also use this method to simply reset the passwords of the existing accounts:

```
SET PASSWORD FOR 'root'@'localhost' = PASSWORD('new_password');
```